# Service Worker Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, cache, offline

My Service Worker Troubles with error, Uncaught (in promise) DOMException. My SW runs perfectly, and gives a prompt to install PWA when on mobile, but it gives this error. My url is [Milyin](https://milyin.com/). It will take 2-3 visits for this error to start coming in Console log.

Just 3 visits caused it to produce over 260 errors for it. I am not able to debug it. I assume that this is because the SW has consumed all storage space in my device. Because if i reload the page using F5, it shows error, but a refresh with CTRL + SHIFT + R, makes no error.

```
//This is the service worker with the Advanced caching

const CACHE = "Milyin";
const precacheFiles = [
  '/',
  '/wp-content/themes/hestia/assets/js/parallax.min.js?ver=1.0.2',
  'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins%3A300%2C400%2C500%2C700'
  ];

// TODO: replace the following with the correct offline fallback page i.e.: const offlineFallbackPage = "/";
const offlineFallbackPage = '/';

const networkFirstPaths = [
  /* Add an array of regex of paths that should go network first */
  // Example: /\/api\/.*/
];

const avoidCachingPaths = [
  '/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-member/',
  '/wp-admin/',
  '/chat/'  
];

function pathComparer(requestUrl, pathRegEx) {
  return requestUrl.match(new RegExp(pathRegEx));
}

function comparePaths(requestUrl, pathsArray) {
  if (requestUrl) {
    for (let index = 0; index < pathsArray.length; index++) {
      const pathRegEx = pathsArray[index];
      if (pathComparer(requestUrl, pathRegEx)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}

self.addEventListener("install", function (event) {
  console.log("[PWA Builder] Install Event processing");

  console.log("[PWA Builder] Skip waiting on install");
  self.skipWaiting();

  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {
      console.log("[PWA Builder] Caching pages during install");

      return cache.addAll(precacheFiles).then(function () {
        if (offlineFallbackPage === "offline.html") {
          return cache.add(new Response("TODO: Update the value of the offlineFallbackPage constant in the serviceworker."));
        }

        return cache.add(offlineFallbackPage);
      });
    })
  );
});

// Allow sw to control of current page
self.addEventListener("activate", function (event) {
  console.log("[PWA Builder] Claiming clients for current page");
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

// If any fetch fails, it will look for the request in the cache and serve it from there first
self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {
  if (event.request.method !== "GET") return;

  if (comparePaths(event.request.url, networkFirstPaths)) {
    networkFirstFetch(event);
  } else {
    cacheFirstFetch(event);
  }
});

function cacheFirstFetch(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    fromCache(event.request).then(
      function (response) {
        // The response was found in the cache so we responde with it and update the entry

        // This is where we call the server to get the newest version of the
        // file to use the next time we show view
        event.waitUntil(
          fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
            return updateCache(event.request, response);
          })
        );

        return response;
      },
      function () {
        // The response was not found in the cache so we look for it on the server
        return fetch(event.request)
          .then(function (response) {
            // If request was success, add or update it in the cache
            event.waitUntil(updateCache(event.request, response.clone()));

            return response;
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            // The following validates that the request was for a navigation to a new document
            if (event.request.destination !== "document" || event.request.mode !== "navigate") {
              return;
            }

            console.log("[PWA Builder] Network request failed and no cache." + error);
            // Use the precached offline page as fallback
            return caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {
              cache.match(offlineFallbackPage);
            });
          });
      }
    )
  );
}

function networkFirstFetch(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request)
      .then(function (response) {
        // If request was success, add or update it in the cache
        event.waitUntil(updateCache(event.request, response.clone()));
        return response;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("[PWA Builder] Network request Failed. Serving content from cache: " + error);
        return fromCache(event.request);
      })
  );
}

function fromCache(request) {
  // Check to see if you have it in the cache
  // Return response
  // If not in the cache, then return error page
  return caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {
    return cache.match(request).then(function (matching) {
      if (!matching || matching.status === 404) {
        return Promise.reject("no-match");
      }

      return matching;
    });
  });
}

function updateCache(request, response) {
  if (!comparePaths(request.url, avoidCachingPaths)) {
    return caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {
      return cache.put(request, response);
    });
  }

  return Promise.resolve();
}
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(async function() {
    // Respond from the cache if we can
    const cachedResponse = await caches.match(event.request);
    if (cachedResponse) return cachedResponse;

    // Else, use the preloaded response, if it's there
    const response = await event.preloadResponse;
    if (response) return response;

    // Else try the network.
    return fetch(event.request);
  }());
});
```

Service Worker is registered through inline JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/SW.js')
  .then(function(registration) {
    registration.addEventListener('updatefound', function() {
      // If updatefound is fired, it means that there's
      // a new service worker being installed.
      var installingWorker = registration.installing;
      console.log('A new service worker is being installed:',
        installingWorker);

      // You can listen for changes to the installing service worker's
      // state via installingWorker.onstatechange
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Service worker registration failed:', error);
  });
} else {
  console.log('Service workers are not supported.');
}

</script>
```

You should definitely see error on repeated visits on pages of my site. Though your mileage my vary based on storage your browser allows.

Answer (score 1):

Service worker only cache origin file, so You dont need to precache cross origin file such as https://fonts.googleapis.com

Or you can try from here https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/foreign-fetch

Comment: Ok, i shall try removing it and let you know